# React Native - fetch to setState returns the old value

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, setstate

I'm trying to update a row in database with API request Post when click in button (cancel or finish).

The value is update correctly in database but when i click button `onPress={() => { settersApi('Finish'); gettersApi(); }}` in `gettersApi()` `console.log(estado)` return the old value from hook "estado".

```
export default Home = ({navigation}) => {
  const [estado, setEstado] = useState([]);

  const gettersApi = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        'http://api/getValues', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
          },
        }
      );
      let json = await response.json();
      setEstado(json);
      console.log(estado);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    gettersApi();
  }, []);


const settersApi = async (param) => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(
      'http://api/setValues', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: estado.id,
          estado: param,
        })
      }
    );
    let json = await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

  
  const CButtons = () => {
   
      return (
        <View>
          <View> 
            <Button
            color='#ffc107'
            title="CANCEL"
            onPress={() => {
              settersApi('Cancel');
              gettersApi();
            }}
            />

            </View>
            <View> 
            <Button
            color='#28a745'
            title="FINISH"
            onPress={() => {
              settersApi('Finish');
              gettersApi();
            }}
            />
            </View>
          </View>
      );
    
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <CButtons></CButtons>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function from `useState` that you called `setEtado`  is a async function. You wont see any changes right away after you change it.

Try to watch the variable state and see when it's updated by using `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(estado);
  }, [estado]);
```

Comment: when i add argument to useEffect cause a infinitive loop